# Why don't we have to declare static functions the same way we need to declare static variables in c++?

Tags: c++, function, variables, static, declaration

Consider the following struct:

```
struct Toto {
    static int a;

    static void Print() {
        std::cout << a;
    }
};
```

And the following main function using the struct in the same cpp file (main.cpp):

```
int main()
{
    Toto::Print();
}
```

Building this gives the following error:

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static int Toto::a"

I understand from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static that

> Static members of a class are not associated with the objects of the
> class

And thus, I've been told we have to define the variable Toto::a outside the struct, in
the translation unit as follow:

```
int Toto::a;
```

From the same source it says that

> Static member functions are not associated with any object.

And that

> Static data members are not associated with any object.

Why do I have to define static variables but not static functions?

Comment: You don't have to separately define the variables if you make them `inline`.

Comment: Definitions of class functions inside the body of the class are [automatically inline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Member_specification). That includes static class functions. Static class member variables aren't inline by default, presumably because they couldn't be inline at all until C++17 and making them inline by default would break existing code.

Comment: Terminology: `static int a;` inside the class definition **declares** `a`. `int Toto::a;` outside the class definition **defines** `a`.

Comment: That's because you have a function *definition* but a variable *declaration*. A declaration alone is not enough, you need a definition elsewhere. Early versions of C++ did not have a way to provide definitions of class-static variables in-class. Now there is a way: `static inline int a = 0;` (from C++17 IIRC), place this inside the class, do not define `a` elsewhere, and forget about the old ugly way.

Comment: The `Print` is implicitly `inline`, because it's a *definition*.  The `a` is not implicitly inline, even if it were assigned a value, because backwards compatibility, so it needs to be explicitly `inline` and probably should be assigned an initial value.  (The repurposed keyword `inline` means *weak linkage*.)

Comment: Wow. Thank you all for your comments. Really helpful! I can't upvote anything with my rep though haha, but mentally add a 1 to each comment and answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static member functions are ordinary functions at the assembly level. The difference is only the hidden pointer 'this' that does not exist in them. They are basically global functions that exist like any other non static or non member (and not inline) function within the C++scope of a class name. Function scopes are C++ thing, they are not there at the CPU level.

Static variables are different. They exist before any class object is created. They are not created when a class instance is created. They are there as globals.

Perhaps it's done the way it's done to emphasize that difference.